# How do I make a sorted list of items based on multiple list of sorted items?

Tags: python, r, sorting

I am trying to get a sorted master list from smaller lists. This can be in python or R.

in R, I have

```
l1<-c("a","c","d")
l2<-c("a","b","e")
l3<-c("a","c","e")
l4<-c("a","b","c","e")
l5<-c("b","c","d")

m<-unique(c(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5))
```

The output I was expecting is `a,b,c,d,e`.

In python

```
l1=["a","c","d"]
l2=["a","b","e"]
l3=["a","c","e"]
l4=["a","b","c","e"]
l5=["b","c","d"]
```

expected result is `["a","b","c","d","e"]`
I started with making a set and going over each list and checking with index but it started getting complex.

Thank you for help.

**EDIT:**
I think I confused you with having a alphabetically sorted list. Those list items could be random. the real order may not be `a,b,c,d,e`.

```
l1=["e","a"]
l2=["e","b","d"]
l3=["b","d","a"]
```

in this case expected order is `["e","b","d","a"]` not `["a","b","d","e"]`

for more clarity, think about few people trying to name US states from east to west.

```
person 1 says, Florida, Louisiana, Nevada,California. 
person 2 says  Alabama, Mississippi, Louisiana, new Mexico, Nevada 
person 3 says Florida, Alabama, Texas, New Mexico, California
person 4 says Alabama, Mississippi, Texas, Nevada
person 5 says Mississippi Louisiana, Nevada
```

and I am trying to get right order from information above.

So, here, We will start with `Florida, Louisiana, Nevada, California`. Now, adding second, it would be, `(Alabama, Florida),Louisiana,New Mexico, Nevada, California.` Adding 3rd (breaks the tie of Alabama/Florida),`Florida, Alabama, Louisiana, Texas, New Mexico, Nevada, California` and adding 4th makes `Florida, Alabama, (Mississippi/Louisiana), Texas, New Mexico, Nevada, California`. adding 5th breaks tie of Mississippi and Louisiana.

Comment: You need to wrap with `sort(m)`

Comment: What is your expected result, in python?

Comment: @Mike  edited the question above.

Comment: @Ananta Are you looking for solution in `R` or `python`

Comment: @akrun does not matter, I have a wrapper for both in my `bash` and I am trying to go with one.

Comment: Are the Characters  only 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'?

Comment: Why is the order `e, b, d, a`

Comment: based on the order of other lists. so, each items should be seeing a flanking items.

Comment: sorry, I am not getting the logic

Comment: @Ananta Are the Characters only 'a', 'b', 'c', ..., 'z'?

Comment: @LeandroHernándezMira No, they could be anything. and their alphanumeric sorting is irrelevant.

Comment: @akrun, what Ananta means is that, for example, the first list orders `e` and `a`, the second list orders `e`, `b`, and `d`, and the third orders `b`, `d`, and `a`.

Comment: See the top of my updated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach in R that turns the vectors into a directed acyclic graph using `tidygraph`, and then uses `node_topo_order` to derive the implied node order. Using your example states from east to west:

```r
l1 <- c("Florida", "Louisiana", "Nevada", "California")
l2 <- c("Alabama", "Mississippi", "Louisiana", "New Mexico", "Nevada" )
l3 <- c("Florida", "Alabama", "Texas", "New Mexico", "California")
l4 <- c("Alabama", "Mississippi", "Texas", "Nevada")
l5 <- c("Mississippi", "Louisiana", "Nevada")

library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
ew_graph <- list(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5) %>%
  map_dfr(~tibble(east = ., west = lead(.))) %>% # turn vectors into edge table
  filter(!is.na(west)) %>%
  as_tbl_graph()

ew_graph %>%  # Now we can order nodes and extract their names as output
  arrange(node_topo_order()) %>%
  pull(name)
#> [1] "Florida"     "Alabama"     "Mississippi" "Louisiana"   "Texas"      
#> [6] "New Mexico"  "Nevada"      "California"
```

Note that there can be more than one correct order and this will only return one of them. If we want, we can also plot the graph to see the relationships more clearly, which reveals that in this data we have a tie between Louisiana and Texas (you can't trace from one to the other), which you missed in constructing the example. It just happens that we have them in the "true" order. If you need to define a separate way of breaking ties, this approach will require some hacking.

```r
library(ggraph)
ggraph(ew_graph) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
  geom_edge_link(
    mapping = aes(start_cap = label_rect(node1.name),
                  end_cap = label_rect(node2.name)),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm'))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Excellent, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Aaaand the actual answer: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Good hunting! :D

This should do it for your original question:

```py
l1=["a","c","d"]
l2=["a","b","e"]
l3=["a","c","e"]
l4=["a","b","c","e"]
l5=["b","c","d"]

s = set()
s.update(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5)
l = sorted(s)
l
#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

For your edited question, let's consider a slight variation on your second example:

```py
l1=["e","a"]
l2=["e","b","d"]
l3=["b","c","a"]
```

(Squint at `l3`.) In this case, the set of lists is underdetermined, as there is no unique ordering between `d` and `c`. Without a rule for deciding ties, no algorithm is possible.

Comment: Please see my edit, I think I confused all of you on assuming that I am trying to get alphabetically sorted list.

Comment: Thanks for updated answer,. If there were 1000s of list where, every scenario is covered, ie `l3` is in fact `b,d,a`; would it be possible?

Comment: "If there were 1000s of list where, every scenario is covered..." Not for sure. It's possible as written. This is a problem in transitive logic, though. Like in Prolog, you'd be able to say "dogs eat cats," "cats eat mice," "x eats y eats z => x eats z", and let Prolog tell you that "dogs eat mice." (Note, that's not Prolog syntax, unless by the dumbest of luck.) Point being, one answer Prolog could give you is that it can't determine if "mice eat birds," for example, if that's not a fact determined by facts that you have introduced.

Comment: Thank you very much, Seems I indeed need graphs. Thank you for helping me explore and making me realize that it is more complicated than I thought. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Python:

```
# Create list of lists
lsts = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]
s = set()

# Add lists to set
for lst in lsts:
  s.update(lst)

# Sort set
sorted(s)
```

**Edit** After OP's update:

```
def sort_lists(lsts):
  list_of_hashes = []
  for lst in lsts:
    list_of_hashes.append({k: v for v, k in enumerate(lst)})

  result_hash = dict()
  for hash_item in list_of_hashes:
    for key, value in hash_item.items():
      if result_hash.get(key):
        result_hash[key] += value
      else:
        result_hash[key] = value
  print(result_hash)
  sorted_results = sorted(result_hash.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
  print(sorted_results)
  return [tup[0] for tup in sorted_results]
```

```
# Test Case 1
l1=["e","a"]
l2=["e","b","d"]
l3=["b","d","a"]

print(sort_lists([l1,l2,l3]))
>> ['e', 'd', 'b', 'a']
```

```
# Test Case 2
s1 = ['Florida', 'Louisiana', 'Nevada', 'California']
s2 = ['Alabama', 'Mississippi', 'Louisiana', 'New Mexico', 'Nevada']
s3 = ['Florida', 'Alabama', 'Texas', 'New Mexico', 'California']
s4 = ['Alabama', 'Mississippi', 'Texas', 'Nevada']
s5 = ['Mississippi', 'Louisiana', 'Nevada']
print(sort_lists([s1,s2,s3,s4,s5]))
>> ['Florida', 'Alabama', 'Mississippi', 'Louisiana', 'Texas', 'New Mexico', 'California', 'Nevada']
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I think I confused all of you on assuming that I am trying to get alphabetically sorted list.

Comment: Thank you for help. But seems, there is something missing and may be I can modify it as I understand your logic. IN my test, I got `['e', 'b', 'a', 'd']` which is wrong just with `l3`, and for states, I got same as yours but have Nevada and California wrong, just from `s1`

Answer (score 0):

My solution has complexity **O(n)**. Other solutions can have O(n log n):

Python: (For R it is similar)

```
l1=["a","c","d"]
l2=["a","b","e"]
l3=["a","c","e"]
l4=["a","b","c","e"]
l5=["b","c","d"]

lsts = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]

solve = []
for p in range(130):
    solve.append(0)

for lst in lsts:
    for p in lst:
        solve[ord(p)] += 1

for idx, value in enumerate(solve):
    if value != 0:
        print chr(idx)
```

This solution is based in values from table ascii.

For your update:

```
l1=["z","c","d"]
l2=["a","b","e"]
l3=["a","c","e"]
l4=["a","b","c","e"]
l5=["b","c","d"]

mySet = set()

mySet.update(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5)

result = sorted(mySet)
print(result)
```